# Angular 9: Chart.js: Monochromatic(Single color with shades) doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, angular9

I wanted to show the monochromatic doughnut graph(Graph with single color with shades). I have graph data and need to show in color shades.

Comment: you can use @Tejashree solution and other option is you can use chartjs color scheme [plugin](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/).

Comment: I have tried the simplest logic. Thanks for your suggestion.@FarhatZaman

Answer (score 0):

I have created the [stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-doughnut-chart-monochrome)z link to show you the code. You can go and check. The output is like below. I have created code in `ngOnInit()` to define color shades.